# Apple pay integration with Stripe (STPTestPaymentAuthorizationViewController in debug)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, stripe-payments, applepay

I am trying to integrate apple pay with stripe in my iOS app.
Using ApplePayStub provide by stripe to check apple pay in DEBUG Mode

I am using the [latest stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) and **ApplePayStub** code from git

Trying to run on **iPhone 6 simulator** and the code that i am using is:

```
paymentController = [[STPTestPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];
((STPTestPaymentAuthorizationViewController*) paymentController).delegate = self;
```

Getting error:

```
Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50 "Your payment information is formatted improperly. Please make sure you're correctly using the latest version of our iOS library. For more information see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios ." UserInfo=0xxxxxxxxxxx {com.stripe.lib:ErrorMessageKey=Your payment information is formatted improperly. Please make sure you're correctly using the latest version of our iOS library. For more information see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios ., NSLocalizedDescription=Your payment information is formatted improperly. Please make sure you're correctly using the latest version of our iOS library. For more information see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios .},
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I get the same error on a device that doesn't support Apple Pay. Looks like the `PKPayment.token` is nil when returned in `didAuthorizePayment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wizyashas, Your setup of the **STPTestPaymentAuthorizationViewController** is perfectly fine. The problem happens when you try to generate the token via **STPAPIClient**. There's where it all gets messy.

This little bit of RnD helped me. Digging into the [**CustomSampleProject**](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example) provided by **Stripe** themselves, **ApplePayStubs** works pretty well when the **STPCard** is recognized when the delegate

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                   didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                            completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion
```

of **PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate** is called. The sample code here checked if the code was run in debug that is for **ApplePayStubs**, the **(PKPayment *)payment** in the delegate is converted to a **STPCard** and is launched to the **STPAPIClient** for **STPToken** generation. Following is the body of the above mentioned delegate:

```
#if DEBUG // This is to handle a test result from ApplePayStubs
if (payment.stp_testCardNumber)
{
    STPCard *card = [STPCard new];
    card.number = payment.stp_testCardNumber;
    card.expMonth = 12;
    card.expYear = 2020;
    card.cvc = @"123";
    [[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:card
                                          completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                        message:@"Payment Unsuccessful! \n Please Try Again"
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            return;
        }
    /*
     Handle Token here
     */
                                            }];
}
#else
[[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithPayment:payment
                                         completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                    message:@"Payment Unsuccessful!"
                                   delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }
    /*
     Handle Token here
     */
}];
#endif
```

This worked for me. With **ApplePayStubs** (on Simulator) and without them (on Device).

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Thanks man, your approach solved the problem. now i am able to test in simulator also. idk how to use "payment.stp_testCardNumber"..?

Comment: How do you want to use it? Can you elaborate a bit. Basically this is the Credit Card number you enter in the textfield where it is required. You can hardcode it to the Default/Test credit card provided by Stripe i.e. 4242 4242 4242 4242 ?

Comment: Yes, i just hardcoded the card data to 4242 4242 4242 4242 as there is no flow for user to add card details outside of apple pay controller

Comment: Wizyashas, yes for ApplePay's implementation in its true sense, user needs to configure Passbook on their phones with their Credit Card details in order to interact between the Passbook and Passkit together. But As ApplePayStubs only accepts 4242... as Credit Card number its alright to hardcode it, but to accept it from yourself, you need to make PTKView in Stripe. You can custom create the PTKView as well by using the components that Stripe provides like PTKCard, PTKCardCVC etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try making request using PaymentKit

```
@IBAction func payTapped(AnyObject) {
    // Valiate that this device can take payments
    if (PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments()) {
        // Construct the basic payment request
        var paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
        paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.example";
        paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = [PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkAmex]
        paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.Capability3DS | PKMerchantCapability.CapabilityEMV
        paymentRequest.countryCode = "US"
        paymentRequest.currencyCode = "USD"
        paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressField.All;

        // Add a line item
        var totalItem = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label:"Foo", amount:NSDecimalNumber(string:"0.05"))
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [totalItem];

        // Show the Apple Pay controller
        var payAuth = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
        payAuth.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(payAuth, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using iphone 6 simulator and i am getting false for PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments()

Comment: In-App Payment Service isn't supported on this device.

Comment: i think it supports on devices only.

Comment: I wanted to test in emulator using ApplePayStub given my stripe